# How can I find frequency of query terms in a document in PHP

Tags: php, search-engine, code-search-engine

Please help me someone as to how to find frequency of each query term in a specific document in PHP. e.g. we have 2 files:

Query.txt contains data "to be not"

Data.txt  contains data "to be or not to be. what to be. everything else to be."

And I need to read the file query.txt and collect terms from that file that are {"to","be"} and find the frequency of these terms in the file data.txt and if there is way to retrieve their positions too.

Result would be probably like that:

"to" appeared 4 times
"be" appeared 4 times
"not" appeared 1 times

Regards,

Comment: _"Query terms"_? What exactly do you mean? Can you give us some sample data for those files, and the expected result?

Comment: Insufficient data- we can't help.

Comment: You need to take a look at `str_word_count()`

Comment: str_word_count() will find the frequency of all words in a document but I want to extract some words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$words = array('to','be','not');

$str = "to be or not to be. what to be. everything else to be.";
$values = array_count_values(str_word_count($str, 1));

foreach($words as $word){
    echo '"'.$word.'" appeared ';
    if(isset($values[$word])){ echo $values[$word]; }else{ echo '0'; }
    echo ' times';
}

?>
```

**PHP with Highlight:**

```
<?php

    $words = array('to','be','not');

    $str = "to be or not to be. what to be. everything else to be.";
    $nStr = $str;

    $values = array_count_values(str_word_count($str, 1));

    foreach($words as $word){
        $nStr = str_replace($word,"<span style='background-color:#FEEFB3;'>".$word."</span>",$nStr);        
        echo '"'.$word.'" appeared ';
        if(isset($values[$word])){ echo $values[$word]; }else{ echo '0'; }
        echo ' times ';
    }

    echo '<br/>'. $nStr;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks pal, it will help me a lot :)

Comment: No problem, love to help!